# Is asking about ownership of warbird wrecks on topic?

Tags: discussion

The question I want to ask pertains to who has the authority or can claim downed warbird wrecks that are still sitting in fields or are in the bottom of our world oceans, lakes, and seas.

Comment: I presumed you meant “warbird” and not “Warburg.” Otherwise I don’t know what Warburg is.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26377/8730) which is very similar and has good answers. Otherwise, Law.se might be a better fit for legalities of sunken wrecks.

Answer (score 0):

The questions which are accepted on this site are covered by the [on-topic help page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

It mentions the folowing

- Flying technique, maneuvers, navigation, procedures, etc.
- Air Traffic Control
- Aviation Weather
- Aviation Regulations
- Aerodynamics (related to aircraft)
- Aviation Safety

As your question doesnt fall in to those categories, it would indicate it *might not* be well received. However there have indeed been similar questions in the past.